# JMeter - how to randomize number of parameters in request

Tags: jmeter

I am new to JMeter.
In my GET request I want to have random number of parameters, so sometimes I want to have:

```
a = value1
a = value2
a = value3
```

and sometimes I want to have

```
a = value1
a = value2
```

etc.

Can I achieve it in JMeter in another way than making separate request modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify parameters dynamically in the *Path* field, using a variable:

[image: dynamic parameters in Path field]

The variable should be created / formatted before HTTP request is sent. For example here I am using counter and BeanShell pre-processor to create a proper set of parameters:

[image: Example: dynamic parameters]

So if I run this with 3 iterations, I will get:

```
GET http://stackoverflow.com/x?a=value0
GET http://stackoverflow.com/x?a=value0&a=value1
GET http://stackoverflow.com/x?a=value0&a=value1&a=value2
```

etc. Of course the logic of creating params should be based on your needs, this is merely an example. The reusable part of that example is saving params in a string, and then saving them into variable:

```
String myDynamicParameters = "";
// your logic here
vars.put("myDynamicParameters", myDynamicParameters);
```

Comment: Thank you! I have to use a little bit different logic, but it is more or less something what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate variable directly inside your GET parameters, the fastest way is to use inline snippets. 
something like:

```
GET http://xx.com/${__Random(1,99999)}
```

Comment: I think the question is about random number of parameters, not random number in parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via i.e. [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) like:

```
sampler.addArgument("name", "value");
```

See:

- [HTTPSasmplerBase.addArgument()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#addArgument(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method JavaDoc
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for comprehensive information on using JMeter and Java APIs in your test.